# How do I select the class of the i element in this list?

Tags: jquery

I need to select the class of the  element in this list item using jquery

The list item is here:-

```
<li><a href="#" title="general news"><i class="icon-rss"></i> news</a></li>
```

I have tried this but no joy, it says undefined:-

```
 $(".btn-group li").click(function () {
    var className = $(this).children("i").attr('class');
    alert(className);
 });
```

Comment: What's the code for the surrounding `ul` or `ol`?

Comment: can you select on an i element?

Comment: <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#" id = "news" etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(this).find("i").attr('class');
```

Answer (score 6):

`i` is not a child of the `li` element, it's a child of the `a` element, hence `$(this).children("i")` returns an empty set.

You can use [`.find` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead, which will search for any descendant:

```
$(this).find('i').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("i").attr('class')`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
 $(".btn-group li").click(function () {
   $(this).find('i').attr('class');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `$(this).children("i")` doesn't return anything, replace it with `$('i', this)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('li').click(function(){
  var className = $(this).find('i').attr('class')
  alert('className is: ' + className)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y6nP7/